# global name 'rank' is not defined

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7

I'm new to Python programming and have problems with this code. rank and suit does not work in method shuffle. My "simple" (?) Question is, why?

```
from Tkinter import *
from Canvas import Rectangle, CanvasText, Group, Window
from PIL import Image
import ImageTk


win = Tk()
text = Text(win, width=65, height=15, font=("Arial", 10))
win.title("Play High or Low Card")
win.geometry("700x600")

class Card(object):

    RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]

    SUIT = ["Python/projekt/bilder/hearts.png", "Python/projekt/bilder/spades.png", "Python/projekt/bilder/diamond.png", "Python/projekt/bilder/clubs.png"]

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.rank + self.suit
        return rep

    def draw(self,suit,rank):

        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.suit).resize((10, 10)))

        cardGraph = Canvas(win, width=70, height=100, bg="White", bd=1, relief='solid', highlightthickness=2)
        cardGraph.photo=bg

        cardGraph.create_image(10,10, image=bg, anchor=CENTER) #left/up
        cardGraph.create_image(53,93, image=bg, anchor=CENTER) #right/down

        cardGraph.create_text(20, 10, text=self.rank, font=("Helvetica", 8, "bold")) #left/up
        cardGraph.create_text(63, 93, text=self.rank, font=("Helvetica", 8, "bold")) #right/down
        cardGraph.create_text(36, 50, text=self.rank, font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold")) #middle

        cardGraph.pack(side = "left", anchor=NW)

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__ (self):
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + " "
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.cards = []

    def add(self, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self, card, other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)

class Deck(Hand, Card):

    def populate(self):
        for suit in Card.SUIT:
            for rank in Card.RANKS:
                self.add(Card(rank, suit))
                DrawCard = Card(rank,suit)
                DrawCard.draw(self,rank)

    def shuffle(self):
        import random
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        DrawCard = Card(rank,suit)
        DrawCard.draw(self,rank)

    def deal(self, hands, per_hand = 1):
        for rounds in range(per_hand):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                         top_card = self.cards[1]
                         self.give(top_card, hand)


                else:
                    print("Cant continue deck. Out of cards!!")



deck1 = Deck()
deck1.populate()
deck1.shuffle()

my_hand = Hand()
your_hand = Hand()
hands = [my_hand, your_hand]

deck1.deal(hands, per_hand = 5)

print(my_hand)


shuffleBtn = Button(win, text="Turn", command=lambda: deck1.shuffle())
shuffleBtn.pack()

mainloop()
```

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RaJ/Desktop/Cards", line 95, in deck1.shuffle()
  File "C:/Users/RaJ/Desktop/Cards", line 77, in shuffle
     DrawCard = Card(rank,suit)
NameError: global name 'rank' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rank and suit are unknown in Class Deck
You seem to expect that they exist in shuffle.
I think you should be grabbing the first card after the shuffle rather than trying to create a new one. i.e.

```
    def shuffle(self):
      import random
      random.shuffle(self.cards)
      DrawCard = self.cards[0]
      DrawCard.draw()
```

and class Card should be modified to not pass suit and rank to draw, they aren't used. self.rank and self.draw are used.

```
    def draw(self):
```

is all that is required in that class